# Reactjs: componentDidMount is not getting called using Link to=""

Tags: reactjs

I have three components to add/view and list users. All of which are getting called from the main container's `componentDidMount` and `render()` method based on `this.props.match.path` property. Please find the container code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { UsersList, ViewUser, AddUser } from '../components';
import { getUsers, getUserDetails } from '../actions';

class Users extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        switch (this.props.match.path) {
            case '/users/:id':
                this.props.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.id);
                break;
            case '/users/add':
                break;
            case '/users':
                this.props.getUsers();
                break;
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.match.path === '/users/add' ? <AddUser onSubmit={this.submit} /> :
                        this.props.match.path === '/users/:id' ? <ViewUser user={this.props.user} /> :
                            <UsersList users={this.props.users} />
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The code in the router file is as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Menu, MenuItem } from '@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <h1 className="App-title">TestUsers</h1>
                </header>
                <Menu>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>
                        Shelves
                        </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem>
                        Products
                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
            </div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/add" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

When I go do addUser component and click on the User's menu to load list of all the users, the component is rendered correctly. But the ComponentDidMount method is not getting called, where the code to retrieve user's from the db exists. Hence the grid is empty. Could anyone let me know, what should ideally be done in this case ? Basically I want to load the list of user's once we go back to /users url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using componentWillReceiveProps instead.

Comment: I tried componentWillReceiveProps instead of componentDidMount. It worked. But it keeps getting called recursively again and again. I found this by console logging in there. What should be causing this to happen.

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=componentWillReceiveProps+getting+called+again+and+again

Comment: Thanks Rahamin, I moved my logic to componentWillReceiveProps and it works. However, it still gets called twice. I thinks some life cycle methods have been deprecated in react fiber. Still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Hmmm... You are right. Didn't know that. They recommend on using getDerivedStateFromProps. Never tried it...